# surefire fails with TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

Tags: maven-3, surefire

I have a multi-module project, and when I execute any goal that includes 'test' the surefire plugin (2.19.1) fails with error:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
```

the unit tests run fine inside eclipse.

Anyone got an idea?

here is the parent pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.tenz.jacks</groupId>
<artifactId>Jacks</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Jacks</name>
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.8</aspectj.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <roo.version>1.3.2.RELEASE</roo.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.67</tomcat.version>
    <jackson.version>2.7.3</jackson.version>
    <spring-security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
</properties>
<modules>
    <module>jacks-config</module>
    <module>jacks-core</module>
    <module>jacks-security</module>
    <module>jacks-web</module>
    <module>jacks-workforce</module>
</modules>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
        <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
        <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
        <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
        <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
<!-- BEGIN: Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END: Testing -->

    <!-- BEGIN: Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END: Logging -->

    <!-- BEGIN: javax.servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END: javax.servlet -->

    <!-- BEGIN: Apache commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END: Apache commons -->  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- BEGIN: AspectJ -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END: AspectJ -->
    <!-- BEGIN: ROO dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${roo.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END: ROO dependencies -->
    <!-- BEGIN: Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>            
    </dependency>
    <!-- END: Spring -->

    <!-- BEGIN: Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
            <!-- <configuration> <webXml>target/web.xml</webXml> </configuration> -->
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- NB: You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see MNG-2972) -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <weaveDirectories>
                    <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</weaveDirectory>
                </weaveDirectories>                    <!--
                  Aspects in src/main/java and src/main/aspects are added
                  as default in the compile goal.
                  Aspects in src/test/java and src/test/aspects are added
                  as default in the test-compile goal.
                  Aspects in src/main/java are added in the test-compile
                  goal if weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder is set to true
                -->
                <weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>false</weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                    <classpathDependencyExclude>de.tenz.jacks:jacks-config</classpathDependencyExclude>
                </classpathDependencyExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>  
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/jacks</path>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-tribes</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ha</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
```

the module pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<parent>
    <groupId>de.tenz.jacks</groupId>
    <artifactId>Jacks</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>jacks-core</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>jacks-core</name>
<dependencies> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.tenz.jacks</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacks-config</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and the annotations of the test where surefire fails:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestJPAConfig.class,TestCoreServiceConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles="test")
@RooIntegrationTest(entity=SystemParameter.class)
@Configurable
```

Comment: Without the code nor the pom file it's more or less impossible to say something helpful...

Comment: I have added the two poms and the annotations.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was that my surefire plugin configuration in my parent pom was 'hiding' classes from the compiler with include and exclude filters, like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*Suite.class</include>
          <include>**/*Test.class</include>
          <include>**/*Tests.class</include>
          <include>**/*Spec.class</include>
          <include>**/*Specs.class</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <include>**/IT*.class</include>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My original intention was to separate longer running tests, but I ended up splitting tests in two because I forgot about this exclusion.

TL;DR:  Surefire finds test classes to execute, but then classes those tests depend on are filtered out by the exclude list.  I think I will change this to use integration packages rather than class names.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, silly me.
The reason was in the parent pom:

```
<classpathDependencyExclude>de.tenz.jacks:jacks-config</classpathDependencyExclude>
```

Wasted two days and half of a night... just don't ask.

I go and hide...

Comment: Could you please explain what was the exact reason?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. So, the exact reason was that all the configuration data contained in the module jacks-config were excluded from the surefire execution.

Comment: I still not get it